# Namespace local variables in clojure

Tags: clojure, namespaces, functional-programming

I have one loop, looping over multiple functions from different namespaces.
So lets say I have (syntax not perfect Im sure):

```
namespace A:
   (defn evaluate [time] ...do calculations that involve running variables that only pertain to current namespace... )

core.clj
:
(loop
     (A.evaluate [(getTimeIncrement)])
)
```

Lets say I need to keep a running total value, running max and running min in evaluate. I dont want to return all of these each time and just pass them back each loop iteration. I feel it would be better to keep these as "namespace local variables" and have those separate from the core file. What would be the "clojure" way of going about this?

Comment: I have a very hard time understanding your question. Take a look at this [article on namespaces](http://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html), maybe this will answer your question or at least help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A.evaluate` is not valid Clojure syntax. I suspect that `[(getTimeIncrement)]` is erroneous as well (this passes a vector containing the result of `(getTimeIncrement)` as the `time` arg of `A/evaluate`. Further, your usage of `loop` won't compile because it does not have a valid binding form, and would not do any looping because it lacks any invocation of `recur`.

On a design level, the idea that a namespace should keep local state is usually misguided in Clojure. Namespaces are each a singleton Class, so any function that tracks state is mixing the concerns of its various callers. The responsibility of a function in functional programming is not to encapsulate a mutable state, it is to encapsulate stateless operations on an immutible input.

All this said, despite the fact that local state is usually a bad idea in Clojure, it is possible to keep mutable local state if it is actually needed (for example, keeping a local store of results for memoization, or timing info for profiling).

```
user> (ns A)
nil
A> (def profile-data (atom {}))
#'A/profile-data
A> (defn evaluate [time]
      (let [random-result (rand)]
        (swap! profile-data assoc time random-result)
        random-result))
#'A/evaluate
A> (in-ns 'user)
#<Namespace user>
user> (loop [i 0]
             (println "evaluated" (A/evaluate (java.util.Date.)))
              (when (< i 10)
                 (Thread/sleep (rand-int 10000))
                 (recur (inc i))))
evaluated 0.3592263204831543
evaluated 0.44324065840598925
evaluated 0.774719597719642
evaluated 0.6153068093424424
evaluated 0.19318953291776575
evaluated 0.7854068601989888
evaluated 0.21019788814948281
evaluated 0.2737466390531492
evaluated 0.1150218371862356
evaluated 0.16852130959555156
evaluated 0.6928076988931166
nil
user> (clojure.pprint/pprint (deref A/profile-data))
{#inst "2014-06-27T19:52:56.036-00:00" 0.2737466390531492,
 #inst "2014-06-27T19:53:20.068-00:00" 0.6928076988931166,
 #inst "2014-06-27T19:52:51.438-00:00" 0.7854068601989888,
 #inst "2014-06-27T19:52:53.038-00:00" 0.21019788814948281,
 #inst "2014-06-27T19:52:43.215-00:00" 0.774719597719642,
 #inst "2014-06-27T19:52:44.204-00:00" 0.6153068093424424,
 #inst "2014-06-27T19:52:49.833-00:00" 0.19318953291776575,
 #inst "2014-06-27T19:53:05.138-00:00" 0.1150218371862356,
 #inst "2014-06-27T19:52:40.595-00:00" 0.3592263204831543,
 #inst "2014-06-27T19:53:11.870-00:00" 0.16852130959555156,
 #inst "2014-06-27T19:52:42.842-00:00" 0.44324065840598925}
nil
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to figure out what OP was asking and answer a question that I'm sure others overlooked due to OP's clear lack of understanding of Clojure syntax. I'm not sure why you were downvoted, this is a great answer!